# BetterSurf Firefox extension appears to be malware

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, malware

When I was browsing (a local copy of a site off my own hard drive), I was greeted by a pop-up that took up the entire bottom half of my screen that detected that I was on the site that had a menu of specials, and this pop-up basically counter-offered me other specials from our client's competitors.

A smaller, similar popup came up on the bottom right of my screen later and made reference to savings.com.

I noticed a new Firefox extension I'd never seen: BetterSurf 1.0. Date it was updated? TODAY.

I'm guessing I somehow got some malware. Could have come from a Firefox or Google Chrome update installation, or perhaps it was from when I downloaded and installed NetBeans 7.4 a couple of weeks ago. (Why, then, would this situation manifest itself NOW?)

I ran MalwareBytes Antimalware (came up with over 100 suspect objects!) and rebooted. I'm not getting the pop-ups any more, and I'm also not seeing any of the subdirectories in C: that are mentioned in any answers.

[image: bettersurf disabled]

What is this extension and why did it appear?

Comment: @dauber It maybe wise to download & run http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

Comment: "Could have come from a Firefox or Google Chrome update installation" - this is not possible, unless you grabbed either browser manually from an untrusted third party site.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer (what worked for me)**: ***disable it and delete the folder "Bettersurf" in the Program Files folder***

**Long answer**: It happened to me after updating firefox to the recent version (25.0). The fact that I didn't install it and firefox add-ons search for the extension doesn't provide any results seems reasonable to me to assume it's a malware. 
So what I did, I disabled it and if you go the Program Files folder, it has created its own folder with the name "Bettersurf" and I deleted it permanently. Restart firefox and the add-on not there anylonger.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be malware and is now officially [blocked](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/) in Firefox. If it wasn't installed knowingly through (running) Firefox, or via a Windows software installation that also informed about adding a Firefox add-on, then it could have been installed on the system by another application (the name could be totally different) that also surreptitiously added a Firefox extension.

It would also be a good idea to further scan the system with two or more anti-malware scanners / live_CD/USB anti-malware kits. Preferably, set the scanners at the highest/strictest levels of detection so as to also detect less rated threats like [PUP](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/4061/potentially-unwanted-program-pup) in addition to viruses, rootkits, trojans, etc.

From the looks of it (no **Remove** button) there could be two possible locations for its installation files:

1. Firefox [install_directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installation_directory)\browser\extensions. Usually only the default theme folder named {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} would be present here though there could also be anti-malware and other legitimate extensions.
2. A location specified in the right pane of the relevant Windows registry [HKCU or HKLM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry#Installation) key (here also there could be listings of anti-malware and other legitimate extensions).

In either case it would be possible to uninstall the extension by [deleting its file(s)/folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Cannot%20uninstall%20an%20add-on#w_globally-installed-extensions), and (if applicable) [deleting the registry key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry#Uninstallation). Please also note that if it appears even after deleting the correct file(s)/folders and/or registry key then most probably there could be another main program or a helper program running constantly or intermittently that re-installs this extension, and possibly changes Firefox settings.

[Troubleshoot Firefox issues caused by malware](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-caused-malware#w_how-do-i-get-rid-of-malware)